# Method: Head on /refresh is returning 500

Tags: spring-boot

/refresh endpoint is added, exposed and I can call directly , but it is not avaialble via the HTTP Method Head ?

2017-02-21 15:00:08.913  INFO [*-*,,,] 4597 --- [main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/refresh || /refresh.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()

Exception:

org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'HEAD' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:20

Comment: The mapping log shows that `/refresh` is registered under `POST` and not `HEAD`. Can you provide a code snippet on how you expose this endpoint?

Comment: this is an actuator endpoint that is exposed internally by the libraray.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this problem only happens when in your micro-service has a `@RestController`.

As I can see, here you are the difference handles in a micro-service with a `@RestController`:

```
2017-02-22 13:54:38.382 **ERROR** [micro-service-1,e9a053f5ffa72714,3980777f97a147f9,true] 10956 --- [http-nio-auto-3-exec-1] c.s.e.c.e.DefaultExceptionHandler
: ErrorResponse [errorCode=90000, description=Request method 'HEAD' not supported, correlationId=e9a053f5ffa72714, externalErrorCode=null, additionalProperties={}]

org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'HEAD' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:314)

...
```

And here you are another one but in this case, has not a `@RestController`:

```
2017-02-22 15:14:49.795  **WARN** [micro-service-2,897590499c7c776c,
74a8108edccafb5e,true]    27623 --- [http-nio-auto-2-exec-5]
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound     : Request method 'HEAD' not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this with the following:

```
@Component
public class ActuatorHeadEndpoint extends EndpointMvcAdapter {

    public ActuatorHeadEndpoint(RefreshEndpoint delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
    @ResponseBody
    @Override
    public Object invoke() {
        if (!getDelegate().isEnabled()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(Collections.singletonMap(
                "message", "This endpoint is disabled"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fran thanks you are right,  that solved the problem its because the class has a @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) , which handles the unspecified exceptions by returning 500 and considers it as internal server error. explicitly defining the HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException as @ExceptionHandler in the advice and handle it with the default actuator JSON response (405) which the spring boot admin expects , everything is normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Spring Boot Actuator. When the management port is different to server port the management stays without the DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver, which is responsible for returning error 405 when the method is not allowed.

This causes problems in Spring Boot Admin because it expects error 405 in some cases instead of any other else. It uses the HEAD method to verify if the endpoint exists. Call the endpoint with the correct method would execute the code, and the idea is only to verify if it exists.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14084